# Show root pages without changing url of the sub folder htaccess rules

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have wordpress site abc.com with urls in this format

URL 1: abc.com/Rebeka/

URL 2: abc.com/shops/Rebeka/

Here for example Rebeka is a post name that exist on root (URL 1) but does not exist under /shops/ folder.

Here I want to keep both of the urls working, only the change is /shops/ folder should show posts from root if it has any missing post.

Could you please help me with htaccess rules for the /shops/ folder or root folder? or any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

In htaccess in the document root :

```
RewriteEngine on
#If /shop/foobar file does not exist 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/shop/$1 !-f
#rewrite /shop/foobar to /foobar (root)
RewriteRule ^shop/([^/]+)/?$ /$1 [L]
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that my site is wordpress site. I also tried your solution by adding it to root .htaccess file, but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /shops/(.*) /$1 [L]
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that my site is wordpress site. I tried this code but it is redirecting my internal page abc.com/shops/Rebeka/ to root abc.com/Rebeka/. I don't want to change ther url abc.com/shops/Rebeka/.

Comment: What this should do is when you request `abc.com/shops/Rebeka/` it will serve whatever `abc.com/Rebeka/` would serve. Isn't this what you wanted to do? Is it doing something else? Does the url change from `shops/Rebeka/` to `/Rebeka/`?

Comment: yes only the problem is URL is changing from shops/Rebeka/ to /Rebeka/ .I don't want to change the URL.

Comment: Can you share your htaccess? Are you sure you don't have `[R=301]` at the end of the rule?

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteRule /shops/(.*) /$1 [L]  
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]  
</IfModule>

Comment: Could you try changing the [L] to [P]?

Comment: Yes but still the URL is changing.

Comment: Do you have it running at localhost? Maybe the redirect is cached.

Comment: No its not on local host? I use ccleaner and ctrl+f5 for cache removal though the output is same.

Comment: I have also generated wordpress new cache from hosting panel as well as tried other themes too.

Comment: I am out of ideas. Maybe try searching for a wordpress plugin to do this for you.